# VS code - formatting arrays in .vue files

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, js-beautify

I have a .vue file which gets auto-formatted when I save it. Thats great and all, but I have a certain problem that I can´t understand, and can´t get rid off.
Following this guide, https://blog.jongallant.com/2019/02/vuejs-vetur-vscode-format-eslint-issues/ , I have setup VS code to use Vetur, beautify-js and ESLint.

In the .vue file I have a simple array. When i save the file it flashes for 100ms like this:

[image]

and then gets saved like this:

[image]

ESLint then complains about two things:

> 'Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 0.eslint(indent)'

and

> 'Trailing spaces not allowed.eslint(no-trailing-spaces)'

I agree with ESLint here and dont want to supress these errors. Every other formatting is fine, but JS not arrays. I believe that this is js-beautify that formats the document like this (hence the linked article :)), but when I disable it the document still gets formatted. But if I set autofix to false in the vue part of eslint.validate (see below), the document is not formatted. So I´m kind of confused here.

This is my settings.json

```
{
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "vetur.validation.template": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.validate": [
    {
      "language": "vue",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "html",
      "autoFix": true
    },
    {
      "language": "javascript",
      "autoFix": true
    }
  ],
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
  "html.format.wrapLineLength": 200,
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 280,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force",
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "js-beautify-html",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
    "js-beautify-html": {
      "wrap_attributes": "auto"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  plugins: ['es-beautifier'],

  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', 'plugin:es-beautifier/standard'],

  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
    // 'no-trailing-spaces': [0],
    // indent: 'off',
    'linebreak-style': 'off',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
  },
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the bottom right corner does it say "Spaces: 8"?

Comment: It says "Spaces: 2". Isn´t this a VS code thing that is overwritten by the formatter?

Comment: @Farsen Have you given Vetur a shot in combination with Prettier instead of beautify-js?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to test and it formatted correctly when using Prettier in combination with Vetur for formatting .Vue files.

Here is how it formatted after saving an example in a .Vue file.

[image: Vue file formatting]

Here is what my settings look like.

[image]

Here is a link to Prettier Code Formatter:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Not sure if swapping extensions is something you are capable of doing with your project, but it does format as you would like and would stop esLint from screaming at you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    return {
      columns: [
        'test', 
        'test2',
        'test3',
        'test4',
        'Pest555',
        '66666666',
        'seven seven seven', 
      ],
    },
```

✅ One line for every element in the array

✅ Every element in the array has one more indentation of the `[` line

✅ ❎ ⚠⚠⚠ There is no spaces after commas ⚠⚠⚠ `,` (But you could add a space if you have a comment inline `, // inline comment`)

✅ Last element has comma to make no differences on git if you add another element.

Also, I prefer 4 spaces indents and double quotes, but it doesn't matter.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mostly agree with your preferences, but I think you misunderstood my question. I am looking for a way to make VS code format my code properly when i save a vue file, without ESlint complaining.